# Remove redundant two way relationships in a Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, tournament

I have a simple model of a chess tournament. It has 5 players playing each other. The graph looks like this:

[image]

The graph is generally fine, but upon further inspection, you can see that both sets
Guy1 vs Guy2,
and
Guy4 vs Guy5
have a redundant relationship each.

The problem is obviously in the data, where there is a extraneous complementary row for each of these matches (so in a sense this is a data quality issue in the underlying csv):

[image]

I could clean these rows by hand, but the real dataset has millions of rows. So I'm wondering how I could remove these relationships in either of 2 ways, using CQL:

1) Don't read in the extra relationship in the first place

2) Go ahead and create the extra relationship, but then remove it later.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

The code I'm using is this:

```
/ Here, we load and create nodes

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///.../chess_nodes.csv' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (p:Player {
  player_id: line.player_id
})

ON CREATE SET p.name = line.name
ON MATCH SET p.name = line.name

ON CREATE SET p.residence = line.residence
ON MATCH SET p.residence = line.residence

// Here create the edges

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///.../chess_edges.csv' AS line
WITH line
MATCH (p1:Player {player_id: line.player1_id})
WITH p1, line
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2:Player {player_id: line.player2_id})
WITH p1, p2, line
MERGE (p1)-[:VERSUS]->(p2)
```

Comment: This is not directly related to your issue, but these queries have a lot of extraneous clauses. 1. The `ON CREATE blah`/`ON MATCH blah` pairs can be replaced by just a single `blah`. 2. None of the `WITH` clauses are serving any purpose, and can be removed.

Comment: For #1, what is the preferred syntax?

Comment: Since you want to perform exactly the same `SET` operations, no matter if the `MERGE` created a new node or matched an existing node, you should not use `ON MATCH` and `ON create` at all. Just perform your 2 different `SET` operations directly: `SET p.name = line.name, p.residence = line.residence`.

Comment: Ahhhh...yes that makes sense. `ON CREATE / ON MATCH` basically just means `SET`. Thanks!!

Comment: but wait. I used `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE` as a solution since my data has some missing values and `MERGE` is lousy with missing values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is obvious that you don't need this extra relationship as it doesn't add any value nor weight to the graph.

There is something that few people are aware of, despite being in the documentation.

`MERGE` can be used on `undirected` relationships, neo4j will pick one direction for you (as realtionships MUST be directed in the graph).

Documentation reference : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html#merge-merge-on-an-undirected-relationship

An example with the following statement, if you run it for the first time :

```
MATCH (a:User {name:'A'}), (b:User {name:'B'}) 
MERGE (a)-[:VERSUS]-(b)
```

It will create the relationship as it doesn't exist. However if you run it a second time, nothing will be changed nor created.

I guess it would solve your problem as you will not have to worry about cleaning the data in upfront nor run scripts afterwards for cleaning your graph.

Comment: Not every player ends up playing each other, though (for example, if you look a the graph you can see Guy3 and Guy5 don't actually play). Would this code snipped create that nonexistent match?

Comment: Well if there is no row in your edges.csv file that represent a relationship between Guy3 and Guy5, no it will not be created

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Something like `MATCH (p1:Player {player_id: line.player1_id}),  (p2:Player {player_id: line.player2_id})
MERGE (p1)-[:VERSUS]-(p2)`. I still get this warning that I've seen before: `This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.`

Comment: If you have an index on :Player(player_id), don't worry about the warning

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest creating a "match" node like so

```
(x:Player)-[:MATCH]->(m:Match)<-[:MATCH]-(y:Player)
```

to enable tracking details about the match separate from the players.

If you need to track player matchups distinct from the matches themselves, then

```
(x:Player)-[:HAS_PLAYED]->(pair:HasPlayed)<-[:HAS_PLAYED]-(y:Player)
```

would do the trick.

Comment: I was planning on using the edges to hold information about the matches...were your recommending a change to the schema? I'd prefer to keep it as it is, and just remove the redundancies.

Comment: Tim - While it might be a good suggestion to have a Match node (or at least make for an interesting discussion), suggesting this doesn't answer the core question of removing redundant relationships.

Comment: With all due respect, the core question isn't the redundant relationships, its how the schema is organized.

Comment: The problem could be solved in many ways, I appreciate both of your time and input immensely as I ramp up my Neo4j understanding. I've already learned so much from SO and all input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the schema has to stay as-is and the only requirement is to remove redundant relationships, then

```
MATCH (p1:Player)-[r1:VERSUS]->(p2:Player)-[r2:VERSUS]->(p1)
DELETE r2
```

should do the trick. This finds all p1, p2 nodes with bi-directional VERSUS relationships and removes one of them.

Comment: Should be 
    MATCH (p1:Player)-[r1:VERSUS]->(p2:Player)-[r2:VERSUS]->(p1)
    WHERE id(p1) < id(p2)
    DELETE r2

Comment: Running your code deleted both directions. I should have read the comment before trying it, which seems to fix it.  But from now on I'll just avoid creating them.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for option #2 in the OP's question. Works great in my case too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UNWIND to do the trick.

```
MATCH (p1:Player)-[r:VERSUS]-(p2:Player)
WITH p1,p2,collect(r) AS rels
UNWIND tail(rels) as rel
DELETE rel;
```

THe previous code will find the direct connections of type VERSUS between p1 and p2 using match (note that this is not directed). Then will get the collection of relationships and finally the last of those relations, which is deleted.
Of course you can add a check to see whether the length of the collection is 2.